# Referencing the geolocation prompt

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a scenario where I need to start a process only after a user clicks to 'Share Location' in the automatic prompt displayed.

Is there anyway I can reference the prompt or detect when a user has clicked to 'share location' or other possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply pass in [a `successCallback` and an `errorCallback`](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface). If one of those is called, then you know that the user has authorized (or declined) the access.

Comment: because the process needs to run while it is detecting.. the process stops running on error or success events